Basic IF THEN ELSE Failure

I have an issue with enabling the motion drive by updating the control power via PLC write. I have followed the learn infosys tuturial for motion and it seems I have a different result than the video. Essentially, when I write true to xControlPower, xEnable should also be true.
How should this be resolved?
I tried clicking PLC write value and the IF true Then (code) does not execute like expected.

is your code actually executing? are you calling the FB / PRG or is picture dircttly written in MAIN?

You should show the entire window of TwinCAT, as @chrisbeardy mentioned, your probably downloaded the code but did not click "play" to run it, since when downloading for the first time it does not run on it's own (unless you enabled it in project properties and activated the configuration).
